# Use Linuxserver's Swag as reverse proxy for SpringBoot application in docker compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt, duck-dns

I am currently experimenting with making my SpringBoot application publicly available from my Pi and found myself in the following situation:

- I have reserved a domain from DuckDns and have the [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/duckdns/) running to update my ip.
- I have my spring application running in a docker container:

```
version: "3"

services:
  my-app:
    container_name: my-app
    image: my-app:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - postgres
      - swag

networks:
  postgres:
    external:
      name: postgres-network
  swag:
    external:
      name: swag-network
```

- I have [Swag](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/swag) running in docker. It creates the "swag" network used in the previous docker-compose. I chose this tool, because it both handles creating the certificate with Let's Encrypt and provides the possibility to setup a reverse proxy. I am not sure though if i really need this tool, or if it's too much.

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  swag:
    image: linuxserver/swag:arm64v8-1.32.0
    container_name: swag
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
      - URL=my-domain.duckdns.org
      - SUBDOMAINS=wildcard
      - VALIDATION=duckdns
      - DUCKDNSTOKEN=my-token
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
    ports:
      - 443:443
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - swag

networks:
  swag:
    name: swag-network
```

- And last but not least the reverse proxy needs to be configured in "config/nginx/proxy-confs/my-domain.subdomain.conf"

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my-domain.duckdns.org;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://my-app:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

But i am unable to connect to the application using my domain.

My questions:

- Do i need to add some https specific config inside the SpringBoot application, or if it's all handled outside of it. For example using port 443, not 8080
- I am very inexperienced with proxies and public availability, so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

  - Is the concept here right?
  - Is the execution right?
  - Is there a smarter/better-practice way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I put the proxy config in the wrong place. To set it globally, I needed to place it in this file:

`config/nginx/site-configs/default.conf`